# Hibernate Interceptor: How do I override onCollectionUpdate and onCollectionRecreate to not populate my entities with database values?

Tags: java, hibernate, interceptor

I am extending org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor to decrypt and encrypt fields. The goal is to always have in-memory domain objects in a decrypted state, and always have the stored database values in an encrypted state.

I have overriden EmptyInterceptor's preFlush and postFlush methods. preFlush encrypts an object's fields, and postFlush decrypt's an object's fields. Whenever Hibernate flushes an object, the fields are saved to the database in an encrypted state. I can continue to access the in-memory object's fields in an unencrypted state. My preFlush and postFlush methods are working well for me.

For many cases, my app needs to load objects that have already been saved to the database. I have overridden EmptyInterceptor's onLoad method to decrypt the values in the database. The loaded objects are in a decrypted state after onLoad is called. However, whenever Hibernate executes an unrelated query, my in-memory object pulls the encrypted values from the database. I am left with an unusable in-memory object that's in an encrypted state.

I suspect that I can override EmptyInterceptor's onCollectionUpdate and onCollectionRecreate, so that hibernate will stop updating my update with values from the database. I tried just setting the collection parameter to null in onCollectionUpdate and onCollectionRecreate, but the problem persists.

Any ideas on how I can stop hibernate from performing collection updates and recreates for objects that need to be encrypted in the database?

Below is a snippet of my CryptoInterceptor class. I have included my current onCollectionRecreate method that sets the collection parameter to null. My onCollectionUpdate method is similar.

```
public class CryptoInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor
{

public static final Set<Class> CRYPTO_CLASSES = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<Class>(Arrays.asList(new Class[]
    { User.class, Order.class, Account.class})));

@Override
public void onCollectionRecreate(Object aCollection, Serializable aKey) throws CallbackException
    {
        PersistentCollection persistentColl = (PersistentCollection)aCollection;

        Object aEntity = null;

        aEntity = persistentColl.getOwner();

       if (aEntity == null)
       {
           return;
       }

        try
        {
            Class clazz = Class.forName(aEntity.getClass().getName());

            if (!CRYPTO_CLASSES.contains(clazz))
            {
                return;
            }
           else
           {
                aCollection = null;
           }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

I know from debugging that Hibernate always passes in an object that implements the org.hibernate.collection.PersistentCollection interface for the collection Object.

Answer (score 1):

I know that is too late for it, but since I found this post useful as a guide for encryption, I will point out that you cannot set

```
 aCollection = null;
```

inside the function, since the collection is an argument and so just a reference to the object. If you really want to do that you should do something like

```
aCollection.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use the [DefaultLoadEventListener](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/event/def/DefaultLoadEventListener.html)
 for the job.. the idea here is to
1. control the loading of objects (collections in particular).
2. control the data in the objects of the collection (encryption & decryption).

There are quite a few listeners which can do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks. In my situation, I think that I should implement the [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/event/PreCollectionUpdateEventListener.html)PreCollectionUpdateEventListener. However, I have no idea how to use such an interface to stop encrypted values from the DB from entering my in-memory objects. I'd really like to stop the CollectionUpdate event from occurring at all. Can I use an event listener to do that?

Comment: yes, in hibernate the event listeners do all the CRUD operations.

if you don;t want something loaded you need to avoid the call to super.<<methodName>> from the overridden method...

its important to note, that loading has 2 types of listeners pre & post..
refer to the link for more details...

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html#d0e865